# object has no attribute 'result_count'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I'm planning on extending Django's change_list template.  Before doing so, I want to ensure I can at least populate the default one.

I'm having difficulty passing the proper information to a copy of Django's default change_list template.

My view:

```
def list(request):
    model = admin.site._registry[NewRequests]
    c = RequestContext(request, {
            'cl': model,
    })
    t = loader.get_template('admin/change_list.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Error when running it:

```
'NewRequestsAdmin' object has no attribute 'result_count'
```

The `search_form cl` is the tag in the template that's causing the error:

```
<div class="module{% if cl.has_filters %} filtered{% endif %}" id="changelist">
  {% block search %}{% search_form cl %}{% endblock %}
  {% block date_hierarchy %}{% date_hierarchy cl %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cl` shouldn't be a model class. It's a queryset.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the answer, but querysets don't have the result_count attribute either.  Any ideas on how this can be added to the object?